# Hash.from_xml(xml from url) resulting in REXML::ParseException The document does not have a valid root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying to convert an xml document to json.

The xml file is loaded from a url:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
```

The url is retrieved by a POST like this:

```
url = params[:q]
```

The url for testing:

```
http://www.fitnessdelivery.nl/feeds/googleshopping.xml
```

The line that results in the error:

```
puts(Hash.from_xml(xml).to_json)
```

The whole error(except from the long long list of products included in the error message:

```
The document "\n\nFitnessdelivery.nl\nhttps://www.fitnessdelivery.nl\nFitnessdelivery.nl,....... werkdag\n0\n1\n\n\n\n" does not have a valid root
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, and how to solve it.

Comment: How do you do this redirect in the controller? The problem is that you are adding to your root `https://fitnessdelivery.nl` the following address as domain `https://www.fitnessdelivery.nl/Fitnessdelivery.nl` which means requesting the router to do a `GET` request for `https://fitnessdelivery.nl/https://www.fitnessdelivery.nl/Fitnessdelivery.nl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the following:

```
url = 'http://www.fitnessdelivery.nl/feeds/googleshopping.xml'
open(url)
```

You will get this error:
    RuntimeError: redirection forbidden: http://www.fitnessdelivery.nl/feeds/googleshopping.xml -> https://www.fitnessdelivery.nl/feeds/googleshopping.xml

As you can see a redirect is attempted. If you change the url to:

https://www.fitnessdelivery.nl/feeds/googleshopping.xml

It should work

A better approach would be to catch the exception and retry:

```
url = 'http://www.fitnessdelivery.nl/feeds/googleshopping.xml'
uri = URI.parse(url)
tries = 3
begin
  uri.open(redirect: false)
rescue OpenURI::HTTPRedirect => redirect
  uri = redirect.uri
  retry if (tries -= 1) > 0
  raise
end
```

In addition Hash.from_xml requires a string - if it is not you get the valid root exception.

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
puts(Hash.from_xml(xml.to_s).to_json)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help. If you like the answer please accept it.